# Connecting to Windows fileserver from outside local network

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, remote-access, file-server

I'm quite new to Windows Server and all its finesse. I have already set up a webserver, fileserver and VPN. What I would like to know is it possible to use the folder I have set up on the fileserver as a network disk outside my local network? I can add the folder I have on the server as a network disk on my desktop computer, but I would also like to access it remotely from my laptop. Is it even possible?

There is a lot of different guides to both fileserver and vpn in internet, but they are quite difficult to understand and I dont' seem to find answer to this question...(It's a bit difficult to explain this in English as it isn't my native language, but hopefully you understand what I mean.)

Answer (score 0):

What is your notebook's operating system?

If Win 7 or above: Have you considered using the "make available offline" feature? As follows:

1. Connect the File Server's shared folder as a network drive on your laptop.
2. right-click this network drive and choose "make available offline".

Provided you have enough disk space on your notebook, the selected folder will be synchronized to your local computer and all changes are resynchronized to the file server when the notebook is in the same network again.

There are also 3rd party tools to achieve the same thing. It's not remote access as you requested, but it might still cover your requirements.

Other than that, you will not get around the need to create some means of communication between your file server and the laptop in the internet. The easiest (though not necessarily most secure) solution would be simple port forwarding. But one would have to know more about your infrastructure to recommend a fitting solution.